# Self-acceleration of a light beam? Airy beam?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, faster-than-light

Can someone provide me with a quick explanation of an *accelerating* (or *self-accelerating*) beam of light? Something called an [Airy beam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_beam) is an example?

I get the impression that an *accelerating Airy* beam, especially a self-accelerating one, is not just a light beam moving through media with successively lower indices of refraction.